# Create Kafka Stream for count amount from value

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I`m producing data like:

```
Key: "Mike", value: {"amount":46,"time":"2021-11-05T07:53:32.005751Z"}
Key: "John", value: {"amount":46,"time":"2021-11-05T07:53:32.005751Z"}
Key: "Mike", value: {"amount":50,"time":"2021-11-05T07:53:32.005751Z"}
```

Key is String (Names like Alice, John...).
For example i need in result:

```
{"Mike": 2}
{"John": 1}
```

or

```
{"key":"Mike", "count": 2}
{"key":"John", "count": 1}
```

I tried next:

```
   public Topology createTopology(){
    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
    // json Serde
    final Serializer<JsonNode> jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
    final Deserializer<JsonNode> jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
    final Serde<JsonNode> jsonSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(jsonSerializer, jsonDeserializer);

    KStream<String, JsonNode> textLines = builder.stream("bank-transactions", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde));
    KTable<String, Long> wordCounts = textLines
            .map((k, v) -> new KeyValue<>(k, v.get("amount").asInt()))
            .groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Integer()))
            .count();

    wordCounts.toStream().to("person-transaction-frequency", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()));

    return builder.build();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties config = new Properties();
    config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "bank-favorite-amount-application");
    config.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:29092");
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
    config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());

    Mc4CalculateFavoriteAmount wordCountApp = new Mc4CalculateFavoriteAmount();

    KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(wordCountApp.createTopology(), config);
    streams.start();

    // shutdown hook to correctly close the streams application
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
}
```

I`m trying to count messages with by names. But i got artifacts in topic:

[image]

Comment: Would you mind showing the streams code you've tried so far?

Comment: @OneCricketeer code was added

Comment: You say you are "producing data like this"... Which does not include `Mike` or `John`, so where did those come from?

Comment: And what are you using to view the actual data? I suggest you start with `kafka-console-consumer`, not a UI tool

Comment: @OneCricketeer Mike, John are keys. I`m using https://www.conduktor.io/

Comment: @OneCricketeer description was refactored

Comment: Okay, so if you just want to count the keys, then why does your code use `v.get("amount")`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer early i had name on value object. But after i moved name in key. I think it will easy to count

Comment: It doesn't really matter where the name is located. I'm asking why you think you need to parse out the `amount` field, or even deserialize the value as JSON if you dont care about the actual values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to count the keys, then you can discard the whole value and replace it with a `1` for every key that is seen.

```
KStream<String, Bytes> textLines = builder.stream("bank-transactions", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Bytes()));
KTable<String, Long> wordCounts = textLines
        .mapValues(v -> 1L)
        .groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()))
        .count();

wordCounts.toStream().to("person-transaction-frequency", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could adapt this [official Confluent Example](https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/create-stateful-aggregation-count/kstreams.html) to your use case. The example is very similar to what you are asking.

To explain this further, you need to create a stream application in which you read data from the topic into a `KStream`. You haven't provided information about your key. In the Confluent example, records are repartitioned explicitly using `map()` method, creating a new `KeyValue` instance for each record (you could do something like using `amount` as key). Then events are grouped by key and counted.

Comment: The question did include information about the key

Answer (score 0):

Count writes the value with Long Serdes, so when you are viewing it using tools like Conduktor, make sure the right value format (long in this case) is used.